# Provide direct access to nested resources in WEB API request without specifying parents?

Tags: rest, web-services

I'm developing a web-api that manages a two level hierarchy objects:
Group -> SubGroup.

- The group are added only by their names and it is a unique identifier for the group
- The sub groups are added only by their names and the group name + sub group name is a unique identifier for the sub group.
- The subgroup can "live" only in the context of its parent (the group).
- Both the group and subgroup have unique ids in the system (besides the names).

The user should have an option to get a certain subgroup details and i'm uncertain if i should give him an endpoint that lets him access it directly.
I researched some threads by didn't get a good answer ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3867344/how-should-i-deal-with-object-hierarchies-in-a-restful-api),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20951419/what-are-best-practices-for-rest-nested-resources),[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9488184/should-i-provide-parent-resource-name-in-url-or-not-in-restful-ws))

**I have two options:**

**Option 1:**

create an endpoint that lets the user to access subgroup only by specifying its name *and its parent group name:*

/groups/subgroups?groupName="x"&subGroupName="y"

**Option 2:**

create a "direct" access endpoint that lets the user access the subgroup directly without specifying the parent group name by using its internal id (In the subgroup creation return this id)
for example:

/subgroups?id="52regfd235fdsf325f" (the id of subgroup "y")

1. What is the best practice for this situation? is adding a "direct" access endpoint to a nested resource is fine or it should be avoided? what will be the case for a subgroup removal endpoint for example? should it be identified by the subgroup id or by its name?
2. In the general case, when we have H1->H2->H3->...Hn hierarchies. For trying to access the last resource in the chain, what will be a good rule of thumb here?